# Python:Pygame: How to animate a ball to move in a sin() like pattern?

Tags: python, animation, pygame, trigonometry

How would you make a ball move in a repetitive wavey pattern just like a sin() graph does?

Comment: The easiest way is to use something like x(t) = t, y(t) = sin(x(t))

You may want to choose a different x(t) though, e.g. slowing down on the "hills" and speeding up in the "valleys" to make the movement appear more realistic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a counter, pygame's [`Clock`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock), or just [`pygame.time.get_ticks`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.get_ticks) to figure out the time.  Here's some sample code to get you started.

```
import math
import pygame

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((400,400))

while True:
    t = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 2  % 400 # scale and loop time
    x = t
    y = math.sin(t/50.0) * 100 + 200       # scale sine wave
    y = int(y)                             # needs to be int

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, (255,255,255), (x, y), 40)

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Would you mind explaining a little more this line:  t = pygame.time.get_ticks() / 2  % 400

Comment: `pygame.time.get_ticks()` returns how many milliseconds since `pygame.init()` was called.  First, I just divided it by two to "slow it down".  Then, `% 400` will make it loop between 0-400.  Strictly speaking, `x = t / 2 % 400` but since I wanted y to be based on the same value, I just set t that way.  Hope that helps.

Comment: For a nicer bouncing use:

````y = 300 - math.fabs(math.cos(t / 15.0) * 100.0)```` 

instead of the line with the sine function. It then also helps to scale the loop to a 16th.